# So there is bpytop from snap

Tags: monitoring

trying to install bpytop the easy way.

```
pytop

Command 'pytop' not found, did you mean:
command 'bpytop' from snap bpytop (1.0.50)
```

OK, lets do it:

```
snap install bpytop
bpytop 1.0.50 from James Tigert (kz6fittycent) installed
root@xxx:/home/xxx# bpytop
Bpytop exited with errorcode (1). See /root/snap/bpytop/186/.config/bpytop/error.log for mor information!

10/12/20 (14:30:13) | ERROR: Data collection thread failed with exception: [Errno 13] **Permission denied**: '/proc/diskstats'
...
10/12/20 (14:30:13) | WARNING: Exiting with errorcode (1). Runtime 0:00:03
```

OK,i understand:

This way bpytop is not allowed to access "hardware"

Any comments?

Guess i better stay the old way:

github -> make install

Comment: Guess you better read the [installation instructions](https://snapcraft.io/install/bpytop/ubuntu), but yeah, this could also be mentioned in the error message ...

Answer (score 5):

In the bug listed https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop/issues/154 and also in the [installation instructions](https://snapcraft.io/install/bpytop/ubuntu) the following lines should be ran after installation:

```
sudo snap connect bpytop:mount-observe
sudo snap connect bpytop:network-control
sudo snap connect bpytop:hardware-observe
sudo snap connect bpytop:system-observe
sudo snap connect bpytop:process-control
sudo snap connect bpytop:physical-memory-observe
```

Comment: @pLumo I guess it would help if I even read those instructions.  =)  I am going to add that to my answer here.  Thank you!  =)

Comment: Hi Terrance, pLumo, works, thanks very much, Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You get neccesary connect commands with

snap info bpytop

```
name:      bpytop
```

summary:   A Python-based resource monitor for your terminal
publisher: James Tigert (kz6fittycent)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/bpytop
contact:   https://github.com/kz6fittycent/bpytop-snap
license:   Apache-2.0
description: |
Resource monitor that shows usage and stats for processor, memory, disks, network and processes.
Python port of bashtop

- Easy to use, with a game inspired menu system.
- Fast and "mostly" responsive UI with UP, DOWN keys process selection.
- Function for showing detailed stats for selected process.
- Ability to filter processes.
- Easy switching between sorting options.
- Send SIGTERM, SIGKILL, SIGINT to selected process.
- UI menu for changing all config file options.
- Auto scaling graph for network usage.
- Shows message in menu if new version is available
- Shows current read and write speeds for disks
- Multiple data collection methods which can be switched if running on Linux

**Once installed, run the following commands so the snap will function as intended:**

`sudo snap connect bpytop:mount-observe`

`sudo snap connect bpytop:network-control`

`sudo snap connect bpytop:hardware-observe`

`sudo snap connect bpytop:system-observe`

`sudo snap connect bpytop:process-control`

`sudo snap connect bpytop:physical-memory-observe`

To run, just type (in your terminal): `bpytop`

*You can make changes to the configs and even add themes here:*

`~/snap/bashtop/current/.config/bpytop`
snap-id: iH0DT1txUogChVISBwaxXrKZVCXifuTL
channels:
latest/stable:    1.0.51 2020-12-25 (197) 278kB -
latest/candidate: ↑
latest/beta:      ↑
latest/edge:      1.0.51 2020-12-21 (197) 278kB -